# How to select the value from dropdown in Selenium WebDriver 3 without id

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to select the value from the corresponding drop-down?

html

```
<select _ngcontent-c13="" class="s_patient_profile_input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" formcontrolname="marital_status">
<option _ngcontent-c13="" value="Single">Single</option>
                                  <option _ngcontent-c13="" value="Married">Married</option></select>

<option _ngcontent-c13="" value="Single">Single</option>

<option _ngcontent-c13="" value="Married">Married</option>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't need to be `id`, you can use any finding strategy as long as the element is a supported dropdown selector. For example, this is by `xpath`:

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//path_to_drop_down")));
select.deselectAll();
select.selectByVisibleText("Value1");
```

Comment: @Sayooj The point was that you are not bound to a specific finding strategy, use whatever works. Can be css, class, xpath, whatever.

Comment: In case he needed further hand-holding, try using `//select[@formcontrolname='marital_status']` for the xpath locator.